# Windows: active window timestamped screenshot via hot key?

Tags: windows, screenshot

Without installing third-party software, is there a way to have a Windows key set to take a screenshot of the currently active window and store it in a timestamped image file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to install a third-party program, [Gadwin Printscreen](https://www.gadwin.com/printscreen/) is a freeware tool that can do most of what you are asking for. You can configure it to bind to <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd>, <kbd>Shift + PrntScrn</kbd>, or other keys. You can configure it to take a screenshot of the entire screen, an individual window, or a rectangular area. You can set it up to save the image to a file, in a variety of formats, and with a timestamp in the filename.

Comment: Thanks Doug, good to know but I'm unable to install third-party software.

Answer (score 0):

To answer one part of your question: Take a screenshot with PowerShell.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/eeff544a-f690-4f6b-a586-11eea6fc5eb8

> This script has a function that allows you to take a screenshot of the
>   entire desktop or of an active window.  Also includes option to save
>   the screenshot to file.

Second part:
Timestamped file with PowerShell 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/1954203/5337091